# Get window of positions around a center point js

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, ecmascript-6

I am trying to figure out how to get a window of positions based off of a center point in JavaScript.

Say I have the following array:
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

If I wanted to get position 5 as the centre point, I'd also like to get positions 3,4,6 and 7 which would produce [3,4,5,6,7].

However, I'm also trying to get it where when it's within reach of the left or right bound of the array, it pushes the window in the opposite direction.
For example if I wanted position 1 I'd like the array to return as [0,1,2,3,4].
Or if I wanted position 0, I'd like the array as [0,1,2,3,4].
The same applies for the end of the array, e.g. I want to get position 8 so I'd return [5,6,7,8,9].

I'm struggling to get this into JavaScript and I feel I am overcomplicating the matter.
My current code is as follows however I am not attached to this code at all so completely changing it is fine:

```
positions() {
    let left = 0;
    let right = 5;
    let middle = this.steps.length / 2;
    // Closer to left.
    if (this.index < middle) {
        if (this.steps[this.index - 2]) {
            left = this.index - 2;
            right = this.index + 2;
        }
        else if (this.steps[this.index - 1]) {
            left = this.index - 1;
            right = this.index + 3;
        }
    }
    // Closer to right.
    else if (this.index > middle) {
        if (this.steps[this.index + 3]) {
            left = this.index - 2;
            right = this.index + 3;
        }
        else if (this.steps[this.index + 2]) {
            left = this.index - 3;
            right = this.index + 2;
        }
        else if (this.steps[this.index + 1]) {
            left = this.index - 4;
            right = this.index + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        left = this.index - 2;
        right = this.index + 3;
    }
    return { left, right };
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can employ some maths to calculate what you get.

1. The start index is the centre point minus the span you want. E.g, centre `5` and span of `2` produces a start position of `5 - 2 = 3`.
2. The end index is the centre point plus the span. E.g., centre `5` and span of `2` produces an end position of `5 + 2 = 7`.

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
       ^   ^   ^
       |   |   |
start -+   |   |
centre +---+   |
end ---+-------+
       |       |
      [3,4,5,6,7]
```

To handle the "overflow" you can clamp the start/end values.

- start cannot be lower than the start of the array (which is `0`).
- while end can be at most the last position of the array (which is `arr.length - 1`).

If the start or end position forms less span than the expected one, the leftover can be transferred to the opposite index:

With centre of `1` and span of `2`:

```
       [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        ^ ^     ^
        | |     |
start --+ |     |
centre ---+     |
padded end -----+
```

With centre of `8` and span of `2`:

```
       [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
                  ^     ^ ^
                  |     | |
padded start -----+     | |
centre -----------------+ |
end ----------------------+
```

Finally, the only situation left to handle is what happens if the array is simply not big enough. That's up to you, just returning the whole array is sensible but also you may choose to throw an error or an empty array. If you are sure it's never going to happen, you can also leave it unhandled.

Here is how the implementation can look

```js
function getRange(arr, pos, span) {
  if ((span*2 + 1) > arr.length) {
    throw Error("not enough items in array"); //or just return arr; or return []; etc.
  }
  
  let start = Math.max((pos - span), 0);
  let end = Math.min((pos + span), arr.length - 1);
  
  const leftoverStart  = span - (pos - start);
  const leftoverEnd    = span - (end - pos);
  
  if (leftoverStart) {
    end += leftoverStart;
  } else if (leftoverEnd) {
    start -= leftoverEnd;
  }
  
  return arr.slice(start, end+1);
}

const arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log(getRange(arr, 5, 2));
console.log(getRange(arr, 1, 2));
console.log(getRange(arr, 8, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var steps = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var res = [];
var i = 3; // index // or 0, 9, 8, 2, 1
var mid = steps.length / 2;

var lenghOfResult = 5;

var left = 0;
var right = 0;

function computed() {
   res = [];
   res.push(i);

   left = i;
   right = i;
   
   for(let c=1;c<=lenghOfResult;c++) { 
      if(steps.hasOwnProperty(i-c) && (i-c <= i-1) && res.length <lenghOfResult) 
      {
        left = i-c;
        res.unshift((i-c));
      }
     if(steps.hasOwnProperty(i+c) && (i+c >= i)  && res.length <lenghOfResult) {
       right = i+c;
       res.push((i+c));
     }
   }
   
   console.log('left', left, 'right', right);
}

computed();

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
const getSlice = (arr,index) => {
    let leftSide = index  - 2;
    let rightSide = index + 2;
    if(leftSide<0){
        return arr.slice(0,5)
    }
    if(rightSide >= arr.length){
        return arr.slice(arr.length-5)
    }
    return arr.slice(index-2,index+3)
}

console.log(getSlice(array,0))
console.log(getSlice(array,1))
console.log(getSlice(array,2))
console.log(getSlice(array,4))
console.log(getSlice(array,7))
console.log(getSlice(array,8))
console.log(getSlice(array,9))
```